# Jenkins doesn't connect to Internet (SSL trouble)

Tags: ssl, jenkins

> Error message: **SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I been trying to configure the proxy correctly but some http servers respond with success, meanwhile all the https doesn't.
I installed all the necessary plugins manually for run a sample pipeline but the error in console output is just a nested page 404 by jenkins.

It's important to know that my OS have the cli internet connection blocked for security terms.
This is the last followable trouble that I have, but I'm a little bit confusing with the **SSL** cert, I tried to resolve it by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore) but is not clear to me which SSL cert I have to download and if this could cause troubles with my PC restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to resolve this issue is change the update url at management plugins > advanced setting > url update from this

> https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

to this

> http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

this solutions is not definitive and i won't recommend it.

Actually i solve this problem loading the plugins.jenkins.io cert to the javas's keystore using

> `.\keytool.exe -import -alias {alias} -keystore %JAVA%\lib\security\cacerts -file \path\to\your\cert`

(Be sure than you are not overwritting anything and the password for -import param by default is *changeit*)